# Rails 5: building new app over old database and have a ForeignKeyViolation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm rebuilding an app on top an existing database. There is some unexpected wiring going on in the database that I am writing a newer Rails 5.0 app on top of to interact with. And I ran into this problem when trying to add a record to the "Volunteer_events" table.

I have a form at "volunteer_events/new"

[image]

My controller looks like this...

```
class VolunteerEventsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_volunteer_event, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /volunteer_events
  # GET /volunteer_events.json
  def index
    @volunteer_events = VolunteerEvent.limit(20)
    volunteer_task_names
  end

  def volunteer_task_names
    @volunteer_task_names = VolunteerTaskType.uniq.pluck(:description)
    # gives me the uniq names of the description column to display in the form dropdown
  end
  # GET /volunteer_events/1
  # GET /volunteer_events/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /volunteer_events/new
  def new
    @volunteer_event = VolunteerEvent.new
    volunteer_task_names
  end
  

  # GET /volunteer_events/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /volunteer_events
  # POST /volunteer_events.json
  def create
    @volunteer_event = VolunteerEvent.new(volunteer_event_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @volunteer_event.save
        format.html { redirect_to @volunteer_event, notice: 'Volunteer event was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @volunteer_event }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @volunteer_event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /volunteer_events/1
  # PATCH/PUT /volunteer_events/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @volunteer_event.update(volunteer_event_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @volunteer_event, notice: 'Volunteer event was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @volunteer_event }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @volunteer_event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /volunteer_events/1
  # DELETE /volunteer_events/1.json
  def destroy
    @volunteer_event.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to volunteer_events_url, notice: 'Volunteer event was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_volunteer_event
      @volunteer_event = VolunteerEvent.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def volunteer_event_params
      params.require(:volunteer_event).permit(:description, :volunteer_default_event_id, :date, :notes, :nowalkins)
    end
end
```

My Model looks like this

```
class VolunteerEvent < ApplicationRecord
  # belongs_to :volunteer_default_event
  has_many :volunteer_shifts, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :resources_volunteer_events, :dependent => :destroy
  validates_associated :volunteer_shifts

  def time_range_s
    return '0-0' if self.volunteer_shifts.length == 0
    my_start_time = self.volunteer_shifts.sort_by(&:start_time).first.start_time
    my_end_time = self.volunteer_shifts.sort_by(&:end_time).last.end_time
    (my_start_time.strftime("%I:%M") + ' - ' + my_end_time.strftime("%I:%M")).gsub( ':00', '' ).gsub( ' 0', ' ').gsub( ' - ', '-' ).gsub(/^0/, "")
  end
end
```

And I have this error...

```
PG::ForeignKeyViolation at /volunteer_events
ERROR:  insert or update on table "volunteer_events" violates foreign key constraint "volunteer_events_volunteer_default_event_id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (volunteer_default_event_id)=(0) is not present in table "volunteer_default_events".
```

What am i missing, doing wrong, there is some unexpected wiring going on in the database that I am writing a newer Rails 5 app on top of to interact with. And I ran into this problem when trying to add a record to the "Volunteer_events" table. What must I do to resolve my error?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You're setting `volunteer_default_event_id` to `0` but there is no entry in `volunteer_default_events` with an `id` of `0`. So you need to stop sending in `0` and/or add some logic to the model to convert that `0` to some valid value. You probably want to uncomment `belongs_to :volunteer_default_event` too.

Comment: Yep, that was it, if you add that as an answer below I'll select it as the ans. for your points.

Comment: As a side note: when when you started building a new app then you should not use Rails 5. I suggest Rails 6.1.4 or even Rails 7.0.alpha

Comment: @spickermann imagine there is a specific reason why I'm using Rails 5.0.7. But do not post said reason as it is out of scope of the question at hand.